# Can't edit Streamfield page after 2.5 upgrade

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I have a site in local dev using Streamfield and 2 custom StructBlock fields. Works fine in 2.4 but after upgrading to 2.5 I can create the page fine in the admin but when I go to edit that page in the admin after saving it get an error. I tried with a fresh database as well but got the same error. Front end of the page works fine.

1. Start a new project with `wagtail start myproject`
2. Create a streamfield page with a custom StructBlock field. (Perhaps even just a built in field, haven't tested that yet.) Save the page.
3. Try to edit the page again.

I also tried with a fresh DB with the same results. Any ideas?

Here is the traceback:

```
Template error:
In template /Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/admin/templates/wagtailadmin/block_forms/stream_member.html, error at line 1
   list index out of range
   1 :  {% extends "wagtailadmin/block_forms/sequence_member.html" %} 
   2 : {% load i18n %}
   3 : 
   4 : {% block hidden_fields %}
   5 :     <input type="hidden" id="{{ prefix }}-type" name="{{ prefix }}-type" value="{{ child.block.name }}">
   6 :     <input type="hidden" id="{{ prefix }}-id" name="{{ prefix }}-id" value="{{ block_id|default:"" }}">
   7 : {% endblock %}
   8 : 
   9 : {% block header_controls %}
   10 :     <div class="sequence-controls">
   11 :         <h3><label{% if child.id_for_label %} for="{{ child.id_for_label }}"{% endif %}>{{ child.block.label }}</label></h3>


Traceback:

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/admin/urls/__init__.py" in wrapper
  102.             return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/admin/decorators.py" in decorated_view
  34.             return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/admin/views/pages.py" in edit
  539.         'has_unsaved_changes': has_unsaved_changes,

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  62.     return template.render(context, request)

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  171.                     return self._render(context)

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  95.     template_rendered.send(sender=self, template=self, context=context)

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py" in send
  175.             for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py" in <listcomp>
  175.             for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/templates/panel.py" in _store_template_info
  157.                         pformatted = force_text(pformat(temp_layer))

File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/pprint.py" in pformat
  58.                          compact=compact).pformat(object)

File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/pprint.py" in pformat
  144.         self._format(object, sio, 0, 0, {}, 0)

File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/pprint.py" in _format
  161.         rep = self._repr(object, context, level)

File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/pprint.py" in _repr
  393.                                                 self._depth, level)

File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/pprint.py" in format
  405.         return _safe_repr(object, context, maxlevels, level)

File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/pprint.py" in _safe_repr
  514.             vrepr, vreadable, vrecur = saferepr(v, context, maxlevels, level)

File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/pprint.py" in _safe_repr
  555.     rep = repr(object)

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/admin/edit_handlers.py" in __repr__
  188.             self.model, self.instance, self.request, self.form)

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/html.py" in <lambda>
  397.     klass.__str__ = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_str(self))

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in __str__
  142.         return self.as_table()

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in as_table
  284.             errors_on_separate_row=False,

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _html_output
  243.                     'field_name': bf.html_name,

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/html.py" in <lambda>
  397.     klass.__str__ = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_str(self))

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py" in __str__
  33.         return self.as_widget()

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py" in as_widget
  93.             renderer=self.form.renderer,

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/core/blocks/base.py" in render
  505.         return self.render_with_errors(name, value, attrs=attrs, errors=None, renderer=renderer)

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/core/blocks/base.py" in render_with_errors
  502.         return mark_safe(bound_block.render_form() + js_snippet)

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/core/blocks/base.py" in render_form
  417.         return self.block.render_form(self.value, self.prefix, errors=self.errors)

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/core/blocks/stream_block.py" in render_form
  141.             for (i, child) in enumerate(valid_children)

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/core/blocks/stream_block.py" in <listcomp>
  141.             for (i, child) in enumerate(valid_children)

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/core/blocks/stream_block.py" in render_list_member
  78.             'block_id': id,

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  62.     return template.render(context, request)

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  171.                     return self._render(context)

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  96.     return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  150.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  95.     template_rendered.send(sender=self, template=self, context=context)

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py" in send
  175.             for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py" in <listcomp>
  175.             for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)

File "/Users/nas/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/templates/panel.py" in _store_template_info
  107.                     pformatted = self.pformat_layers[index]

Exception Type: IndexError at /admin/pages/4/edit/
Exception Value: list index out of range
```

Comment: Did you upgrade to Django 2.2 at the same time as upgrading Wagtail? If so, you probably need to upgrade django-debug-toolbar. See https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/5277

Comment: I didn't realize I updated Django too since I updated Wagtail using pip and the requirements.txt file. Once I removed django-debug-toolbar it works fine.