# Snippets aren't displayed in the wagtail admin page

Tags: django, wagtail

I have a snippet called event, After upgrading to wagtail 2.5.1 (Still i am not sure if this issue is related to version 2.5.1) The previous events aren't displayed on the wagtail admin page anymore. However i am able to search for them in the search box.any help is appreciated

Comment: Check your logs for template errors (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47722888/1853523 for how to enable them), and if you've defined a `__str__` method on your snippet model, check it for possible error conditions (e.g. following a foreign key field that allows nulls). My guess is that an error is happening while outputting the snippet listing, causing the listing to be left out of the page.

Comment: The previously described issue appear on our staging server. on my local machine the events are shown but when trying to edit them i got the same error as:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56023562/cant-edit-streamfield-page-after-2-5-upgrade